# Trigger for SFTP files in Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-functions, sftp, azure-logic-apps

[image]

I have created the logic app for SFTP with sftp-ssh connection inorder to process large files as When files added or modified in SFTP ( Properties Only).

Once the file arrives in SFTP I'm moving the file to the Azure Blob Storage. Now my issue is when I drop some 15 files at a time only 3 or 4 getting suceeded and remaining files failed with error as provided path doesn't exists. When I resubmit the file it is suceeding. I have defined number of file to trigger as 20 and given to trigger for every 5 minutes.

Getting error as :

```
{
  "status": 404,
  "message": "The provided path '/abc/Test/file1.txt' does not exist.\r\nclientRequestId: 7a23df8-31be-43f4-8153-aaadcvfg5f1e",
  "error": {
    "message": "The provided path '/abc/Test/file1.txt' does not exist."
  },
```

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce your problem, but the whole process is fine, can you show us a screenshot of your logic app design? Besides, can you tell us how large your file is?

Comment: Attached the image link of my Logic app Design. When I load single file of size 500 MB  it is working fine. However, when I copy bulk of files of less size (10MB) at single time it is processing only certain files and remaining failing with below error: {
  "status": 404,
  "message": "The provided path '/abc/Test/file1.txt' does not exist.\r\nclientRequestId: 7a23df8-31be-43f4-8153-aaadcvfg5f1e",
  "error": {
    "message": "The provided path '/abc/Test/file1.txt' does not exist."
  },

Comment: I'm not sure if the logic instance run in parallel affects your logic app. As a suggestion, you can try to click the button in the upper right corner, select `settings`, you can try to enable or disable `Concurrency Control` and test with adjust the number of Degree of Parallelism.

Comment: I have set  How often do you check for items as 5 minutes. Enabled the concurrency limit and adjusted the Degree of Parallelism to 2 . Dropped multiple files in SFTP. However, still it is failing for some of the blobs as Provided path does not exists.